# Upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 missing software & Updates, Software updater and screen lock

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-center

I updated my computer from 20.04 to 22.04 and am missing software & Updates, Software updater and screen lock from the Activities search.  It seems possible that I am missing other items as well. I was able to get back software & updates by running

> sudo apt-get  install software-properties-gtk

Why am I missing these, and how to add back?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. If presented with a list of packages, read it carefully to ensure it's what you really want.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.